# OnDraw instead of spline, it draws circles

Tags: android, graphics, paint, alpha

/I got the following code:

```
public class SketchActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnSeekBarChangeListener {

private MyView myView;

private Button clearBtn;

private ToggleButton embossBtn, blurBtn, eraseBtn, srcaBtn;

private RelativeLayout layout, layout2;

private TextView penSizeTxt;

SharedPreferences pref;

private Preview preview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    init();
    preview = new Preview(this);

    layout2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_layout2);
    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.paint_layout);
    layout.addView(preview);
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            myView = new MyView(SketchActivity.this, layout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight());

            layout2.addView(myView);
            layout2.bringToFront();

        }
    }, 50);

    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);

    mEmboss = new EmbossMaskFilter(new float[] { 1, 1, 1 }, 0.4f, 6, 3.5f);
    mBlur = new BlurMaskFilter(8, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL);
}

private void init() {

    clearBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearBtn);

    embossBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.embossBtn);
    blurBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.blurBtn);
    eraseBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.eraseBtn);
    srcaBtn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.srcatopBtn);

    clearBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    embossBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    blurBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    eraseBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    srcaBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private static Paint mPaint;

private MaskFilter mEmboss;

private MaskFilter mBlur;

public void colorChanged(int color) {
    mPaint.setColor(color);
}

private void setToggleOf() {
    embossBtn.setChecked(false);
    eraseBtn.setChecked(false);
    blurBtn.setChecked(false);
    srcaBtn.setChecked(false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == embossBtn.getId()) {

        if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mEmboss) {
            setToggleOf();
            mPaint.setXfermode(null);
            mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mEmboss);
            embossBtn.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            embossBtn.setChecked(false);
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == blurBtn.getId()) {

        if (mPaint.getMaskFilter() != mBlur) {
            setToggleOf();
            mPaint.setXfermode(null);
            mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(mBlur);
            blurBtn.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            blurBtn.setChecked(false);
        }
    } else if (v.getId() == eraseBtn.getId()) {
        if (eraseBtn.isChecked()) {
            setToggleOf();
            eraseBtn.setChecked(true);
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

        } else {
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            mPaint.setXfermode(null);
            mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);

        }
    } else if (v.getId() == srcaBtn.getId()) {
        if (srcaBtn.isChecked()) {
            setToggleOf();
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            srcaBtn.setChecked(true);
            mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));
            mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
        } else {
            mPaint.setMaskFilter(null);
            mPaint.setXfermode(null);
            mPaint.setAlpha(0xFF);
        }

    }

    else if (v.getId() == clearBtn.getId()) {
        layout2.removeAllViews();
        myView = new MyView(SketchActivity.this, layout.getWidth(), layout.getHeight());
        layout2.addView(myView);
    }

}

public class MyView extends View {

    private static final float MINP = 0.25f;

    private static final float MAXP = 0.75f;

    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    private Canvas mCanvas;

    private Path mPath;

    private Paint mBitmapPaint;

    Bitmap bitmap;

    int x = 0;

    int y = 0;

    int r = 0;

    public MyView(Context c, int width, int height) {
        super(c);

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        int w = display.getWidth(); // deprecated
        int h = display.getHeight();
        // setFocusable(true);
        // setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.download);

        // setting paint
        mPath = new Path();
        mPaint = new Paint();

        mPaint.setAlpha(0);
        mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);

        this.getContext().getResources();

        Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.smoke);
        Bitmap bm2 = getResizedBitmap(bm, h, w);

        // converting image bitmap into mutable bitmap

        bitmap = bm2.createBitmap(w, h, Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mCanvas.setBitmap(bitmap); // drawXY will result on that Bitmap
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(bm2, 0, 0, null);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        //mCanvas.drawCircle(x, y, r, mPaint);

        // canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

    }

    private float mX, mY;

    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        // mPath.lineTo(x, y);
        // mCanvas.drawPoint(x, y, mPaint);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if ((dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) || (dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE)) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
        // invalidate();
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();
        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);

            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return mBitmap;
    }
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    penSizeTxt.setText(String.valueOf(progress + 2));

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    // RECREATE THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}

}
```

I want it to clear the second layout and show the content of the camera, on touch. So that if i make a curved line with my finger on the screen it would set those pixels to alpha, and see the camera from the back layout. The problem is that if for example, i make a curved line, the app erases the content of that curve too. So that if i would make a circle with my finger it would erase the content of the circle too, not only the margin.

A screenshot with how it looks: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlYgU.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onCreate i had:

```
mPaint = new Paint();
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPaint.setDither(true);
mPaint.setColor(0xFF000000);
mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
mPaint.setStrokeWidth(5);
```

And then on my View i had:

```
 mPaint = new Paint();
 mPaint.setAlpha(0);
 mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
 mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
 mPaint.setMaskFilter(new BlurMaskFilter(10, BlurMaskFilter.Blur.NORMAL));
```

Overriding the mPaint, and that's what made it not work properly. By deleting the second:

```
 mPaint = new Paint();
```

I made it work